# Verificar campos ao dar submit e caso erro voltar ao campo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tenho um formulário bem extenso e gostaria de ao clicar em submit e o campo estiver com erro, que a página possa fazer um scroll (jQuery) até este campo para que a pessoa saiba exatamente o que tem erro. Comecei assim:

```
$("#sdEmpresa").removeClass("hidden").css("border", "1px dashed red");
```

Então, consegui agilizar isto:

```
if(empresa == ""){

        // callback method use this space how you like
        var body = $("html, body");
        body.animate({scrollTop:0}, 1500, function(){
            $("#sdEmpresa").removeClass("hidden").css("border", "1px dashed red");  
        });

}
```

Aqui ele volta pro body, como voltar para `#sdEmpresa`?

Comment: não precisa usar `body.animate`, basta dar focus no campo. Vai ser difícil dar uma resposta mais completa pois cada campo possui uma regra... Já pensou em usar algum plugin para validação?

Comment: Eu até pensei @PapaCharlie mas as minhas validações são bem específicas, mas poderia colocar esse código modificado para que o scroll vá em cima do campo? Aprendendo jQuery (rsrsr)

Comment: Geralmente os plugins possuem uma vasta regra de validações... Recomendo dar uma olhada pelo menos. Não entendi o final do comentário, você quer que eu de um exemplo do focus?

Comment: Se puder, serei grato em ver como esse código poderia funcionar da forma que eu busco.

Comment: Use `$('#sdEmpresa').focus();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue abaixo um pequeno exemplo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/n99uv76w/)

**jquery:**

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var erro = false;
    var elemento;

    // limpar marcação de erro da tentativa anterior:
    $('form div').removeClass('erro');
    $('.msg-erro').remove();

    // percorrer todos os input e verificar se estão em branco ou não
    $(this).find('input:not(.nao-obrigatorio)').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            erro = true;
            elemento = $(this);
            return false;
        }
    });

    // aqui pode adicionar outras verificações especificas como combos ou checkbox.
    // definir erro = true e elemento = ao elemento causador do erro.

    if (erro == true) {
        elemento.parent('div').addClass('erro').append((elemento.data('erro') ? '<span class="msg-erro">'+elemento.data('erro')+'</span>' : ''));
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: elemento.offset().top - 100 }, 500);
    } else {
        // não tem nenhum erro, fazer os procedimentos de envio
        alert('Formulario enviado!');
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="name">* Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="nome" data-erro="Preencha seu nome">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">* E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" data-erro="Preencha seu e-mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Telefone</label>
        <input type="text" id="telefone" class="nao-obrigatorio">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Celular</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="nao-obrigatorio">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">* Endereco</label>
        <input type="text" id="endereco">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">* Cidade</label>
        <input type="text" id="cidade">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">* Estado</label>
        <input type="text" id="estado">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">* Pais</label>
        <input type="text" id="Pais">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que você quer ir para o elemento `#sdEmpresa`

```
if(empresa == ""){
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#sdEmpresa").offset().top
    }, 1500);  
}
```

Mas acho que você deve pensar uma maneira de otimizar essa validação, usando um plugin, ou percorrer todos `<inputs>` da página de uma só vez, ao invés de ir testando um por um como você mostrou no exemplo:`if(empresa == "")`.